# The create_profile_job() method is not accepting the new parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to use a Lambda function (written in python) to create a series of profile jobs in DataBrew. AWS recently added a new parameter to this function ("Configuration) which I have added in my code. However, when I call the function, I get the following error message: "Unknown parameter in input: "Configuration", must be one of: DatasetName, EncryptionKeyArn, EncryptionMode, Name, LogSubscription, MaxCapacity, MaxRetries, OutputLocation, RoleArn, Tags, Timeout, JobSample." This does not match the parameter list in the boto3 documentation, which was recently updated to align with the new features added to DataBrew on 07/23/21. Has anyone else had this issue? If so, is there a timeline for this bug to be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the version of boto3 that is available in Lambda by default is not the most updated version. Hence, in order to use all the parameters for this method, you have to add the latest version of boto3 (and all dependencies) as a Lambda layer.